# Passing string from C++ to C++/CLI

Tags: c++, c++-cli, interop, marshalling

I have in my C++/CLI project some native functions and a ref (managed) class that exposes them to a C# project.

One of the functions that it exposes returns a `WCHAR*` string (AKA `LPWSTR` / `wchar_t*`).
 When I ran the C# program which prints it, all I could see is square symbols.

I've set a breakpoint at the native return statement and the debugger shows that the returned string is correct.
Then I stepped over **once** and landed in the managed function (which has a `WCHAR*` variable that's set to the returned value), and somehow it shows those square symbols.

It seems like once the string enters the managed "section" it gets messed up.
I'd show my code but the issue happens before I even convert the `WCHAR*` string into `System::String` so it doesn't really matter.

Code sample as requested:

```
static String^ GetWindowTitle(IntPtr windowHandle)
{
    HWND hWnd = (HWND)windowHandle.ToPointer();
    LPWSTR nativeTitle = NativeGetWindowTitle(hWnd).get();
    String^ title = gcnew String(nativeTitle);

    return title;
}
```

Comment: Please add code sample.

Comment: What is `NativeGetWindowTitle`? Why are you using C strings here? Surely you should be using `std:wstring`? What makes you believe that `nativeTitle` will still be valid when you pass it to the `String` constructor? It seems hard to imagine that it could be.

Comment: NativeGetWindowTitle(hWnd).get() -> are you calling get() on a temporary here?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The native method calls a function which requires a `LPWSTR` parameter. I don't know why that matters. it works.

Comment: @stijn Yes. the native function returns `unique_ptr<WCHAR[]>`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The temporary should be destroyed at the end of the function, but it doesn't matter since the new instance of `System::String` copied it before. That's my assumption.

Comment: doesn't the pointer get destroyed right after the `LPWSTR nativeTitle=...` line already, yielding nativeTitle invalid?

Comment: @stijn Correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't it last until the end of the function? like any other local variable??

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'll give it a try. It solved it! thank you all very much, I've learned a lot from this issue!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at this line:

```
LPWSTR nativeTitle = NativeGetWindowTitle(hWnd).get();
```

it seems clear that `nativeTitle` points to memory owner by the temporary object returned by `NativeGetWindowTitle(hWnd)`. But that temporary has gone by the time you pass `nativeTitle`.

According to the C++ standard:

> Temporary objects are destroyed as the last step in evaluating the full-expression that (lexically) contains the point where they were created.

Assuming that everything else that we cannot see, works correctly, you can fix your problem by making sure that the object returned by `NativeGetWindowTitle(hWnd)` lives beyond the `gcnew` statement.